# Amazon ECS "the referenced cluster was inactive"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I followed the steps to install the ECS client on Ubuntu 16, but when I try to run the ECS container agent, it keeps restarting and when I have a look at the logs

```
2016-12-07T06:01:39Z [INFO] Starting Agent: Amazon ECS Agent - v1.13.1 (efe53c6)
2016-12-07T06:01:39Z [INFO] Loading configuration
2016-12-07T06:01:39Z [INFO] Checkpointing is enabled. Attempting to load state
2016-12-07T06:01:39Z [INFO] Loading state! module="statemanager"
2016-12-07T06:01:39Z [INFO] Event stream ContainerChange start listening...
2016-12-07T06:01:39Z [INFO] Detected Docker versions [1.17 1.18 1.19 1.20 1.21 1.22 1.23]
2016-12-07T06:01:39Z [INFO] Registering Instance with ECS
2016-12-07T06:01:39Z [ERROR] Could not register module="api client" err="ClientException: The referenced cluster was inactive.
    status code: 400, request id: 9eaa4124-bc42-11e6-9cf1-7559dea2bdf8"
2016-12-07T06:01:39Z [ERROR] Error registering: ClientException: The referenced cluster was inactive.
    status code: 400, request id: 9eaa4124-bc42-11e6-9cf1-7559dea2bdf8
```

I didn't find a reference for this error on google and I'm wondering what's wrong...

Do I need to create the cluster name on the ECS dashboard ?
I have attacher the container role to my EC2 instance, which allows for cluster creation so I don't think the problem comes from here...

My docker run config

```
sudo docker run --name ecs-agent \
--detach=true \
--restart=on-failure:10 \
--volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
--volume=/var/log/ecs/:/log \
--volume=/var/lib/ecs/data:/data \
--net=host \
--env=ECS_LOGFILE=/var/log/ecs-agent.log \
--env=ECS_LOGLEVEL=info \
--env=ECS_DATADIR=/data \
--env=ECS_CLUSTER=my-cluster \
--env=ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE=true \
--env=ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE_NETWORK_HOST=true \
amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `aws ecs create-cluster --region $REGION --cluster my-cluster`, call the `CreateCluster` API through the SDK, or create it in the console.  The ECS agent will only automatically create a cluster named `default`, and only when `ECS_CLUSTER` is unspecified.

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't realize the ` AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole` didn't include the authorization to create load balancers. But are you sure the cluster would not be created automatically if appropriate permissions were given ?

Comment: Yep, the logic is [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/blob/v1.13.1/agent/api/ecsclient/client.go#L101-L120); it only ever creates `default` and only if `ECS_CLUSTER` is not specified (I wrote some of this code).